# How to play shared video on the same Facebook page instead of a new window

Tags: html, facebook, video, facebook-opengraph

Video shared perfect but video play in new window but I want play video   in same Facebook page.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"     xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta property="og:video" content="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf?config={'clip':{'url':'http://103.231.125.106/nesos/videoappsuser/150930171515SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb.mp4'}}" />
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf?config={'clip':{'url':'https://103.231.125.106/nesos/videoappsuser/150930171515SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb.mp4'}}" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="400" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="300" />
```